# Debug dotnet unmanaged memory leak with LLDB in Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, memory, memory-leaks, lldb

I have an application which memory consumption grows slowly but continuously. A dashboard I built with event counters and Grafana shows that heap size, gen[0-1-2] size, loh size, poh size, assembly count and jitted bytes are constant, but the working set keeps growing. It gets to 5Gb in a week, despite of the application heap using 2Gb.

I have checked with the `free` command, and there was only ~700Mb buffered.

I know how to use `dotnet-dump``lldb`to debug a managed memory leak, but not how to debug an unmanaged memory leak. All info I find is about WinDbg and the command`heap`which I do not have in`lldb`. How should I proceed?

Comment: did you get some useful information